# Symbol’s function definition is void

Tags: functions, variables

I am trying to make an interactive toggle in `emacs 27.0.90`

When I `eval-region` no warnings or errors are shown.

However, when I do `(helm/toggle-frame)` in `ielm` it throws
`Symbol’s function definition is void: helm-in-frame-p`

Here is the code,

```el
(let ((helm-in-frame-p t))
  (defun helm/toggle-frame ()
    "Toggle helm in frame or in buffer.
    Default is buffer because it is faster on Xforwarding."
    (interactive)
    (setq helm-in-frame-p (not helm-in-frame-p))
    (if (helm-in-frame-p)
        (progn
          (global-set-key (kbd "M-x") 'helm-M-x-in-frame))
      (progn
        (global-set-key (kbd "M-x") 'helm-M-x)))
    (message "Helm in frame is now %s"
             (if helm-in-frame-p "Enabled" "Disabled"))))
```

Here is the `ielm` output

```
ELISP> helm/toggle-frame
*** Eval error ***  Symbol’s value as variable is void: helm/toggle-frame
ELISP> (helm/toggle-frame)
*** Eval error ***  Symbol’s function definition is void: helm-in-frame-p
```

Comment: I presume you've set `lexical-binding` for this library?

Comment: yes, in fact, I've tried turning off lexical scoping and using a separate setq statement without let binding; same errors

Comment: Yep; I was just asking in case that was going to be an additional problem once you'd solved the immediate one.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You define a local *variable*, then later call a non-existent *function* with the same name in the `if`:

```
(if (helm-in-frame-p)
```

Drop the surrounding parentheses and it should work again.